# What is the correct pattern for working without deferred constraints?

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I am using databases that aren't Oracle or Postgresql, which means I don't have access to deferred constraints, which means that constraints must be valid at all times (instead of just on commit).

Let's say I'm storing a linked list type structure in a database like so:

```
id     parentId
---------------
1      null
2      1
3      2
4      3
5      4
6      5
```

`parentId` is a foreign key reference to `id`, and is required to be unique via a constraint.

Let's say I wanted to move item `5` to sit just before item `1`, so our DB would look like this:

```
id     parentId
---------------
1      null
2      5 <-- different
3      2
4      3
5      1 <-- different
6      4 <-- different
```

Three rows need to be altered, which is three update statements. Any one of these update statements will cause a constraint violation: all three statements must be complete before the constraint would be valid again.

My question is: **what is the best way of not violating the uniqueness constraint?**

I can currently conceive of two different solutions, neither of which I like:

- Set each affected `parentId` to `null` and *then* perform the three updates
- Completely change my data model so it's more of a 'copy on write' style versioned database, where these sorts of issues are not a problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I can't think of anything (DBMS-agnostic at least) that's better than changing stuff to null, but there's got to be another way.

Comment: "Three rows need to be altered, which is three update statements". Or it could be one `UPDATE` statement affecting three rows. That would work in SQL Server. What DBMSs are you actually using?

Comment: @MartinSmith, you mean with CASE statements? ( http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/) I did not know you could do that... And the DB is currently SQLite, but will probably move onto MySQL at some point.

Comment: @SCdF - Either with `CASE` statements or by using a table expression that contains multiple values. (e.g. `VALUES` clause or table valued parameter). That all applies to SQL Server though. Not sure what the SQLite behaviour is / options are.

Comment: Depends on what else you are doing and how many, but remove them from the table (into a temp table?) square them up and then put them back, maybe?

Comment: @MartinSmith, just tried a case statement in SQLite, it doesn't work, the uniqueness constraint still fires. nulling out each affected row's parent id first "fixes" it, so back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query.  I'm sure there are many variations of this, but here is what I would use...

```
DECLARE
  @node_id         INT,
  @new_parent_id   INT
SELECT
  @node_id         = 5,
  @new_parent      = 1

UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  parent_id = CASE WHEN yourTable.id = target_node.id    THEN new_antiscendant.id
                   WHEN yourTable.id = descendant.id     THEN target_node.parent_id
                   WHEN yourTable.id = new_descendant.id THEN target_node.id
              END
FROM
  yourTable          AS target_node
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS descendant
    ON descendant.parent_id = target_node.id
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS new_antiscendant
    ON new_antiscendant.id = @new_parent_id
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS new_descendant
    ON COALESCE(new_descendant.parent_id, -1) = COALESCE(new_antiscendant.id, -1)
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON yourTable.id IN (target_node.id, descendant.id, new_descendant.id)
WHERE
  target_node.id = @node_id
```

This will work even if the @new_parent_id is NULL or the last record in the list.

MySQL doesn't like self joins in updates, so the approach would probably be to do the LEFT JOINs into a temporary table to get the new mapping.  Then join on that table to update all three recors in a single query.

```
INSERT INTO
  yourTempTable
SELECT
  yourTable.id    AS node_id,
  CASE WHEN yourTable.id = target_node.id    THEN new_antiscendant.id
       WHEN yourTable.id = descendant.id     THEN target_node.parent_id
       WHEN yourTable.id = new_descendant.id THEN target_node.id
  END             AS new_parent_id
FROM
  yourTable          AS target_node
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS descendant
    ON descendant.parent_id = target_node.id
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS new_antiscendant
    ON new_antiscendant.id = @new_parent_id
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable          AS new_descendant
    ON COALESCE(new_descendant.parent_id, -1) = COALESCE(new_antiscendant.id, -1)
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON yourTable.id IN (target_node.id, descendant.id, new_descendant.id)
WHERE
  target_node.id = @node_id

UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  parent_id = yourTempTable.newParentID
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  yourTempTable
    ON yourTempTamp.node_id = yourTable.id
```

*(The exact syntax depends on your RDBMS.)*